# How to view array from truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am trying to view the values of candidate[] using the truffle console, how do i do that?

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Voting {
    uint public votingCount = 0;
    address public admin;

    struct Candidate {
        string cName;
        uint candidateVoteCount;
    }

    Candidate[] public candidates;

constructor() public {
        admin = msg.sender;

             candidates.push(Candidate({
                cName: 'Testing',
                candidateVoteCount: 0
             }));
    
    }
```

I have tried calling it with "testing = await.Voting.deployed()" then "preview = testing.candidates[]". Which doesnt seem to work.